# cURL does not send postfields

Tags: php, curl

I have been reading documentation and queries for several hours and I think I have a correct POST made with cURL.

It communicates correctly, because I receive the auth key and OK is validated, but then it doesn't receive any parameters from the post. I think some parameter must be missing, but I don't see anything in the documentation.

My code:

```
$data = "email=name@xxxx.com&template=3";
$url = "https://xxxx.net/xxx/aaa/bbb"; 

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "keyname: keyvalue"
            ));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Does anyone know if I should stick some more configuration??

Comment: I checked your code sample in a local server, and output `$_POST`, it returns me the email and template as expected. The problem must be elsewhere. Can you share how you process the POST data ?

Comment: thank you for your time. My curl destination receives JSON.stringify(req.query).
I know that it works because with postman (POSTing the URL with parameters "https://xxxx.net/xxx/aaa/bbb?email=name@xxxx.com&template=3" + Appi Key Auth) it works